# Modify QTableWidgetItem context menu when editing

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, contextmenu, qtablewidgetitem

I'm trying to add actions to the context menu that pops up when I right click while editing a cell’s content in a `QTableWidget`. I tried redefining the `contextMenuEvent()` method from `QTableWidget` but it is never called in this context. I also tried to call `cellWidget()` method on the items, but as I expected it returned `None`. I'm guessing that a temporary `QLineEdit` widget is created whenever a cell is in edit mode but couldn't find anything to confirm that.

Is there any way to access the context menu of `QTableWidgetItem`s when in edit mode?

I've looked extensively through the documentation but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context menu that you must handle is the editor provided by the delegate. So in this case a QStyledItemDelegate must be implemented:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class StyledItemDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = super().createEditor(parent, option, index)
        if isinstance(editor, QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
            editor.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
            editor.setProperty("index", QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(index))
            editor.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.handle_context_menu)
        return editor

    def handle_context_menu(self, pos):
        editor = self.sender()
        if isinstance(editor, QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
            index = editor.property("index")
            menu = editor.createStandardContextMenu()
            action = menu.addAction("New Action")
            action.setProperty("index", index)
            action.triggered.connect(self.handle_add_new_action_triggered)
            menu.exec_(editor.mapToGlobal(pos))

    def handle_add_new_action_triggered(self):
        action = self.sender()
        if isinstance(action, QtWidgets.QAction):
            index = action.property("index")
            print(index.row(), index.column(), index.data())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(3, 5)
    delegate = StyledItemDelegate(view)
    view.setItemDelegate(delegate)
    view.resize(640, 480)
    view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```